# A propriedade ou o indexador "MailAddress.DisplayName" não pode ser atribuído, pois é somente leitura

Tags: c#, .net, envio-de-email

Já consigo mandar um e-mail normalmente. Só não consigo mudar `DisplayName`.

Segue código :

```
var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
var message = new MailMessage();
message.From.DisplayName = "Nome Nome";
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("you@email.com"));
message.Subject = "Teste Subject";
message.Body = string.Format(body);
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
    await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
}
```

Na linha `message.From.DisplayName = "Nome Nome";`, como eu posso mudar `DisplayName` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa criar um objeto para usar no `From`:

```
var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
var message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("sender@email.com", "Nome Nome");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("you@email.com"));
message.Subject = "Teste Subject";
message.Body = string.Format(body);
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient()) {
    await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/SendMailFrom.cs).

Comment: Nice brother !!!